# How do I unzip all files in a folder using 7-zip in batch?

Tags: batch-file

The title kind of says it all. I'm not sure how to do this, and the other post at
[Unzip all files in a folder using 7zip in CMD line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18984789/unzip-all-files-in-a-folder-using-7zip-in-cmd-line/18985107#18985107)

explains nothing to me very coherently. Could someone please help me with a simple way of unzipping all .zip files inside a specific folder?

Comment: you can do it without using external tools - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28043589/how-can-i-compress-zip-and-uncompress-unzip-files-and-folders-with-batch

Answer (score 46, accepted):

This will unzip all zip files in the current folder(into the same folder), assuming you have installed 7zip into `C:\Program Files\7-Zip` location.

If you have added your 7zip folder into the path, you can just enter 7z instead of the fullpath

```sh
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" e *.zip
```

Comment: How would I do it so that I can choose which folder I want to unzip it into?

Comment: You just have to add the -o switch. Following our previous example you could use "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" e *.zip -oc:\temp\destination

Comment: Magical, for mine it was each zip was in another folder so  it was  "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" e */*.rar

Comment: wonderful but when i try to unzip file_name.tar.gz output is only file_name.tar is there a way to unzip file without containing folders?

Answer (score 11):

Just to add up on [Gabor's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31460643/how-do-i-unzip-all-files-in-a-folder-using-7-zip-in-batch/31460816#31460816).
My default installation folder was `C:\Program Files (x86)\7-Zip` so I'm going to go from there.
Here is the link to download [7zip](http://www.7-zip.org/download.html).

I wanted to unzip every zip file in a directory into multiple folder. however the `e` in the previous answer export everything in the directory.

Here is for the "normal" unzip creating a folder per zip file unzipped:

```sh
 "C:\Program Files (x86)\7-Zip\7z.exe" x *.zip
```

And to have a full details of what you can do with 7z.exe use the `--help`:

```sh
 "C:\Program Files (x86)\7-Zip\7z.exe" --help
```

Here is its output:

```sh
Usage: 7z <command> [<switches>...] <archive_name> [<file_names>...]
       [<@listfiles...>]

<Commands>
  a: Add files to archive
  b: Benchmark
  d: Delete files from archive
  e: Extract files from archive (without using directory names)
  l: List contents of archive
  t: Test integrity of archive
  u: Update files to archive
  x: eXtract files with full paths

<Switches>
  -ai[r[-|0]]{@listfile|!wildcard}: Include archives
  -ax[r[-|0]]{@listfile|!wildcard}: eXclude archives
  -bd: Disable percentage indicator
  -i[r[-|0]]{@listfile|!wildcard}: Include filenames
  -m{Parameters}: set compression Method
  -o{Directory}: set Output directory
  -p{Password}: set Password
  -r[-|0]: Recurse subdirectories
  -scs{UTF-8 | WIN | DOS}: set charset for list files
  -sfx[{name}]: Create SFX archive
  -si[{name}]: read data from stdin
  -slt: show technical information for l (List) command
  -so: write data to stdout
  -ssc[-]: set sensitive case mode
  -ssw: compress shared files
  -t{Type}: Set type of archive
  -u[-][p#][q#][r#][x#][y#][z#][!newArchiveName]: Update options
  -v{Size}[b|k|m|g]: Create volumes
  -w[{path}]: assign Work directory. Empty path means a temporary directory
  -x[r[-|0]]]{@listfile|!wildcard}: eXclude filenames
  -y: assume Yes on all queries
```

Answer (score 5):

I am not sure about the OP's intent but I think it is a good idea to have a subfolder for each .zip file, so that files with the same name will not get overwritten. (Just like when you drag and drop with the right mouse button multiple .zip files and select 7-Zip > Extract Files ... from the local menu.)

For this I use this at the command line:

```
for /f "usebackq delims=" %f in ( `dir /b /s *.zip` ) do 7z x "%f" -o"%~pf%~nf"
```

If you do not have 7-Zip's program folder in your `PATH` environment variable, you need to write its full path. On x86 Windows or x64 Windows with x64 7-Zip:

```
for /f "usebackq delims=" %f in ( `dir /b /s *.zip` ) do "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" x "%f" -o"%~pf%~nf"
```

On x64 Windows with x86 7-Zip:

```
for /f "usebackq delims=" %f in ( `dir /b /s *.zip` ) do "C:\Program Files (x86)\7-Zip\7z.exe" x "%f" -o"%~pf%~nf"
```

Note: cmd substitutes `%~pf` with the path (actually directory name, including a backslash at the end) of the variable `%f`, and `%~nf` with the filename (without file extension).

Answer (score 1):

You can use x instead of e this will allow you to extract each zip file in folder with zip file name.

```
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" x *.zip
```

example you have list of zip file

```
file001.zip
file002.zip
fileXXX.zip
```

will extract into /file001 , /file002, /fileXXX in same folder where zip file located.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. 7z wants to write all files into the same (base) folder where all the zip files are located.

Answer (score -2):

for non batch users,

- Open 7-zip
- Navigate with 7-zip to the folder where your .7z or .zip or .rar files are located.
- Select all .7z  or .zip or .rar files
- Click in 7-zip on the extract button
- Click "OK" in the next pop-up window to extract to the same location.

Comment: OP is looking for a solution in a batch file.