# Uncompress recursively using 7-Zip from command line

Tags: 7zip

I'm attempting to uncompress several .gz files using 7-Zip from the command line. My files are in directories like so:

```
Desktop/copyto/1/
    file1.gz
    file2.gz
Desktop/copyto/2/
    file1.gz
    file2.gz
    file3.gz
```

I would like to recursively uncompress all the .gz files into each's orginal location and as well as deleting the remaining .gz files when they are done uncompressing.

I have tried the following command with no luck:

```
7z.exe x C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\Desktop\copyto\*\*.gz -r
```

I assumed that this would extract recursively. I get the error:

```
Processing archive: C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\Desktop\copyto\1\file1.gz
Can not open output file file1
Sub items Errors: 1
```

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18984789/unzip-all-files-in-a-folder-using-7zip-in-cmd-line This maybe helpful.

Comment: @ProGamingHun I've looked at that but couldn't seem to get anything to work.

Comment: cross post http://superuser.com/questions/942044/uncompress-recursively-using-7-zip-from-command-line

Answer (score 0):

Given your command line, my guess is that your current working directory isn't any subdirectory of your home directory (`C:\Users\MYUSERNAME`) or the public user directory (`C:\Users\Public`), which means you probably don't have access rights. For example, if I run the following from `C:\Program Files\7-Zip`, I get the same error with a 7-Zip file:

```
C:\Program Files\7-Zip>7z x C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\Desktop\migrated\annex_k.7z -r

7-Zip [64] 9.38 beta  Copyright (c) 1999-2014 Igor Pavlov  2015-01-03

Processing archive: C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\Desktop\migrated\annex_k.7z

ERROR: Can not open output file : .\annex_k\include\annex_k\errno.h
Skipping    annex_k\include\annex_k\errno.h
ERROR: Can not open output file : .\annex_k\include\annex_k\handler.h
Skipping    annex_k\include\annex_k\handler.h
...
Extracting  annex_k\include\annex_k
Extracting  annex_k\include
Extracting  annex_k

Sub items Errors: 10

Archives with Errors: 1

Sub items Errors: 10

Kernel  Time =     0.031 =   39%
User    Time =     0.031 =   39%
Process Time =     0.062 =   78%    Virtual  Memory =      3 MB
Global  Time =     0.080 =  100%    Physical Memory =      4 MB
```

Notice that not even an `annex_k` directory was created:

```
C:\Program Files\7-Zip>dir /b
7-zip.chm
7-zip.dll
7-zip32.dll
7z.dll
7z.exe
7z.sfx
7zCon.sfx
7zFM.exe
7zG.exe
descript.ion
History.txt
Lang
License.txt
readme.txt
```

The solution is to extract to a directory in which you have access rights. You can specify an output directory using something like `-oC:\Users\MYUSERNAME\Desktop\copyto\1`. If you absolutely need to do this in a directory in which you don't have write access ordinarily, you'd need to run the command prompt as an administrator and extract the file as usual.